# Efficient way for slicing a input string and turning variables into integers or float in python

Tags: python, variables, input, slice

In [urionlinejudge.com.br](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br), a lot of their beginner problems consists in a single line input, where you slice it in different variables and put them in a formula or something.

Example, the input consists of 3 numbers in a single line, and I need to sum them all. So the input could be 10 5 6, and the output should be 21.

For now what I've been doing is the following:

```
var_a, var_b, var_c = input().split(' ')
var_a = int(var_a)
var_b = int(var_b)
var_c = int(var_c)

#some generic code for sum of the variables
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing the first part of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm *assuming* you are using `str.split` instead of the non-existent `str.slice`.

For the sum, you can feed a list of strings to `sum` and `map`:

```
res = sum(map(int, input().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

efficient? I'm not sure. Prettier and Pythonic? Hell yeah.

```
input_str = input()
input_list = input_str.split(' ')

# And now you can iterate over this list and cast it into integers:

# list
vars = [int(i) for i in input_list]

result = sum(vars)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split and map to int on the same line.

```
var_a, var_b, var_c = list(map(int, input.split()))
```